# Push a property value of an item in a List to next Item in that list

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, foreach

I have two objects say Amount, NewAmount both having below properties

```
public class Amount
{
    public Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public Int64 Amt1 { get; set; }
    public Int64 Amt2 { get; set; }
} 
public class NewAmountDo
{
   public Int64 newAmt { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of Amount with some values in it and a NewAmount Object with one value

```
List<Amount> amountListObject = new List<Amount>();
Amount amount = new Amount();
Amount amount1 = new Amount();
Amount amount2 = new Amount();
Amount amount3 = new Amount();
NewAmountDo newAmountDo = new NewAmountDo();
newAmountDo.newAmt = 50;
amount.Id = 1;
amount.Amt1 = 10;
amount.Amt2 = 100;
amountListObject.Add(amount);
amount1.Id = 2;
amount1.Amt1 = 20;
amount1.Amt2 = 200;
amountListObject.Add(amount1);
amount2.Id = 0;
amount2.Amt1 = 30;
amount2.Amt2 = 300;
amountListObject.Add(amount2);
amount3.Id = 0;
amount3.Amt1 = 40;
amount3.Amt2 = 400;
amountListObject.Add(amount3);

Console.WriteLine("Input ");
exising = amountListObject;

List<Amount> intermediate = new List<Amount>();
Amount newamount = new Amount();
intermediate.AddRange(amountListObject);
intermediate.Add(newamount);
```

I am trying to add the value in the property newAmt in NewAmount Object to the Amt1 property of the amountListObject and push down the value of Amt1 to the Amt1 value of the next listitem. But I am getting the value of the first Amt1 in all the Amt1 in the List. below is the code I tried

```
for (int i = 0; i < intermediate.Count; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {
       intermediate[i].Amt1 = newAmountDo.newAmt;
    }
    else
    {
       intermediate[i].Amt1 = exising[i - 1].Amt1;
    }
}
```

Following is the Input:

```
Id : 1 , Amt1 : 10 , Amt2 : 100
Id : 2,  Amt1 : 20 , Amt2 : 200
Id : 0 , Amt1 : 30 , Amt2 : 300
Id : 0 , Amt1 : 40 , Amt2 : 400
```

Below is the result I am getting

```
Id : 1 , Amt1 : 50 , Amt2 : 100 
Id : 2 , Amt1 : 50 , Amt2 : 200
Id : 0 , Amt1 : 50 , Amt2 : 300
Id : 0 , Amt1 : 50 , Amt2 : 400
Id : 0 , Amt1 : 50 , Amt2 : 0
```

Expected result:

```
Id : 1 , Amt1 : 50 , Amt2 : 100
Id : 2 , Amt1 : 10 , Amt2 : 200
Id : 0 , Amt1 : 20 , Amt2 : 300
Id : 0 , Amt1 : 30 , Amt2 : 400
Id : 0 , Amt1 : 40, Amt2 : 0
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you copy references of your Amount objects between the 2 lists. So when you copy the amount from the previous element to your intermediate list, you basically overwrite the value that you are going to use in the next loop.

I see 3 solutions to your problem:

1. Use a **struct** instead of a **class** for your *Amount* type. This will do value-copy instead of a reference copy so you won't have the same instance in the 2 lists and you won't have any conflicts.
2. If you really need your type to be a **class**, you can do a copy constructor and copy your items in the intermediate list like this:

   ```
   intermediate.AddRange(amountListObject.Select(o => new Amount(o)));
   ```

   This way, you will still have references in your lists but each reference will point to a different instance of your type Amount, hence no conflicts.
3. If you want to avoid any copy of objects, then you would need to modify your code to use an intermediate value in your foreach to keep what was in the previous Amount like this:

   ```
   Int64 previous;
   for (int i = 0; i < intermediate.Count; i++)
   {
       if (i == 0)
       {
           previous = intermediate[i].Amt1;
           intermediate[i].Amt1 = newAmountDo.newAmt;
       }
       else
       {
           Int64 temp = intermediate[i].Amt1;
           intermediate[i].Amt1 = previous;
           previous = temp;
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

First declare constructor for the defined class it will help with the initialization and gives a better readability to the code.

```
public class Amount
    {
        public Int64 Id { get; set; }
        public Int64 Amt1 { get; set; }
        public Int64 Amt2 { get; set; }

        public Amount(Int64 Id, Int64 Amt1, Int64 Amt2)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.Amt1 = Amt1;
            this.Amt2 = Amt2;
        }
    }
    public class NewAmountDo
    {
        public Int64 newAmt { get; set; }

        public NewAmountDo(Int64 newAmt)
        {
            this.newAmt = newAmt;
        }
    }
```

Now the initialization will be much cleaner:

```
List<Amount> amountListObject = new List<Amount>();

Amount amount = new Amount(1,10,100);
Amount amount1 = new Amount(2,20,200);
Amount amount2 = new Amount(0,30,300);
Amount amount3 = new Amount(0,40,400);
NewAmountDo newAmount = new NewAmountDo(50);
amountListObject = new List<Amount>() { amount, amount1, amount2, amount3 };
```

Now the fixed problem:

```
Int64 shiftedAmt = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < amountListObject.Count; i++)
        {                
            /* First element in the list */
            if (i == 0)
            {
                /* save the amt1 property value for shifting */
                shiftedAmt = amountListObject[i].Amt1;
                /* Switch to the new amount (if you need to add the new to the old just replace with +=) */
                amountListObject[i].Amt1 = newAmount.newAmt;
            }
            else
            {
                /* Shift the value */
                Int64 temp = amountListObject[i].Amt1;
                amountListObject[i].Amt1 = shiftedAmt;
                shiftedAmt = temp;
            }
        }
        /* Create new Amount object for the last shifted amt1 value */
        Amount _amount = new Amount(0, shiftedAmt, 0);
        amountListObject.Add(_amount);
```